# If I turn off iCloud backups for an app, will it affect it?

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, storage

I am running low in iCloud storage, so if I turn off backups for certain apps, will it be affected? For example let’s say it’s social media, will the photos or videos be lost?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Ask Different.

Your question can't be answered properly because it depends on the app your referencing.

Some apps need real-time access to the data they store in your iCloud or they won't work properly; some don't.  Some apps will function fine without this access and some won't even start-up.

I recommend that if you're not sure, contact the developer of the app and ask them.  You can also turn off iCloud and then check the app, too.

Comment: The user is talking about ICloud *backup*, not *data storage*

Comment: Thanks @nohillside I understand.  The answer still holds true, I believe.  It all depends on how the app developer stores the app data (local vs iCloud) and I don't think there's a 'general' answer to the OPs question.  It would have to be focused on a specific app to answer the question correctly.

Comment: Well, an application which only works if backup is enabled is seriously broken, IMHO.

Comment: @nohillside Yes, I agree.  However, we both know there's many seriously poorly written apps in the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll lose all stored data of the specific app (supposing that the app is already backed up on iCloud).